# Having trouble deleting a prefab after instantiating inside a coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm initiating prefab inside a coroutine and deleting it after one second like this:

```
Vector2 spawnPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f,5.0f));
Instantiate(_Confirm, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
Destroy(_Confirm);
```

But the only problem is the object won't get deleted. I even tried `SetActive(false)`, but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Full Code:

```
_tick.SetActive(true);
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        _soilPatch=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Selected");
        Instantiate(_flower,new Vector3(_soilPatch.transform.position.x,_soilPatch.transform.position.y+1.3f,_soilPatch.transform.position.z),Quaternion.identity);
        _soilPatch.tag="Untagged";
        _soilPatch.SetActive(false);
        _uI.SetActive(false);
        _tick.SetActive(false);
        Vector2 spawnPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f,5.0f));
        GameObject g = Instantiate(_Confirm, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Destroy(g)
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to destroy the prefab, not the GameObject instantiated. Is that what you are trying to do or do you want to destroy the GameObject?

Comment: Does your console throw any errors?

Comment: @Geeky Quentin, no console errors.

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT I tried destroying the game object as well.

Comment: @GeekyQuentin The code prior to that is completely irrelevant, just setting some game objects on and off

Comment: Alright, can you mention the reason why Absinthe's answer doesn't work?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin It just doesn't. The gameobject just stays there.

Comment: @GeekyQuentin could it be because I already have another yield return new WaitForSeconds(1) in the same coroutine?

Comment: Add a `Debug.Log` statement after `yield return ...` code and mention if there's any output or not

Comment: Yes! you can't have two `yield return new ...` in one IEnumerator. That's why you have to post complete code in your IEnumerator along with the function.

Comment: @GeekyQuentin I added the whole code, I commented out one of the yield returns, but I still get the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246838/discussion-between-geeky-quentin-and-vchuckshuna).

Comment: @GeekyQuentin Hey it's okay, I figured out what's wrong. Now I need to find a solution.

Comment: Cool, mention your now problem in a new question, lemme see it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a reference to the object you're instantiating:

```
Vector2 spawnPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f,5.0f));
GameObject g = Instantiate(_Confirm, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
Destroy(g);
```

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Try `DestroyImmediate`. What happens when you `g.SetActive(false)`? Also, describe why it doesn't work in more detail, what do you do, what happens?

Comment: neither works.

The gameobject just stays there.

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging then and provide more information. Set a breakpoint, attach to Unity and step though - is `g` the object you expected? Is `_Confirm` instantiated several times? The process of destroying an object is simple so I suspect there's something elsewhere in the code causing the issue. Post any code that could be related.